# refedit sum in textbox

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I have a UserForm with refedit, textbox, and command button **controls**.

I would like the user to be able to select a range of cells from the active worksheet with the refEdit control, and as the range values are selected, the sum of its values are displayed in the text box.

Once the total of the ranges are selected, the user will click the command button, which should **copy the value from textbox, close current UserForm, open another UserForm and paste the value into a textbox**.

However, when I click the refEdit control, it only shows the refEdit textbox by minimizing the user form until the button is clicked. How can I prevent this from happening?

Also, the code I wrote for the textbox doesn't work, in fact it doesn't do anything:

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
     txtbxSum.Value = Sum(RefEdit1.Value)
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Have you done any research that led you to believe that what you're trying to do is even *possible*?  For one thing, `RefEdit` controls haven't been supported in Excel for over a decade, and articles like [this one](//peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/) illustrate that, and suggest alternatives. I'm all for learning, but I would suggest that you begin with a more realistic/achievable goal to familiarize yourself with Excel/VBA basics. Also, check out "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve] plus [these tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1):

The `RefEdit`control has its issues, so it may not be the best design choice. As Ashleedawg commented, [see here](https://peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/)

That said, the `RefEdit.Value` property is a string representing the selected range.  So to Sum that range you need to use

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
    txtbxSum.Value = Application.Sum(Range(RefEdit1.Value))
End If
```

Note that `RefEdit1_Change` fires every time the Selected Range changes (so if the user drags over a 3 cell range it will fire three times).  If you also have a `txtbxSum_Change` event it will fire each time the `refedit1_Change` event updates the 
Textbox with new value, ie as the selected range Sum changes.